# How to set up a default value for key/value (hstore) control in QGIS 3.x?

Tags: qgis

It seems that PostgreSQL sintax doesn´t work. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Try AND instead of a comma

Comment: Default value for a key/value control doesn´t use a "logical" expression. It needs a valid value for the data type (5 for integer, "text" for string, etc.). The problem is the sintax for the hstore field in the PostgreSQL table that I am using.

Comment: try with `map_to_hstore( map( 'key', 'value' ) )` ... can't validate right now, so no answer. the relevant functions (*Expression String Builder*) are in the *Maps* section.

Comment: I have tried but it doesn´t work. But if I check "apply default value on update" and I change another field value, and save layer, it works properly. So maybe it could be a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This UI field is a QGIS expression, not a postgresql expression. To build a map in a QGIS expression, use the map function:

```
map('fieldname1', 'value1', 'fieldname2', 'value2')
```

The ε button is your friend...